# height: 100% won't keep ratio of image

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, blogger

I'm having an issue with Blogger again. I'm styling the starting page. I do want to showcase snippets and titles in tiles, which do have a fixed height(200px) but dynamic width, so it's working responsively.

On hover I do want to show the first image, as a background and a "read more" button.
Since I can't use

```
background: url(data:post.firstImageUrl);
```

I have to find a solution using the image tag.

My fallback works great because it's defined as a background and has background-size contain added.

What I try to achieve with the preview image, though is a look like like *background-size cover* would work.

I tried using

```
img{
  height: 100%
  min-width: 100%; 
}
```

But it didn't work. The whole area is covered up but the image is stretched and not scaled with the correct aspect ratio.

I really hope someone has an idea how I can get it to work.
Best would be a CSS only solution, but if there's something you can do with javascript I'd appreciate it as well

Here's my testblog: http://einneuertestblog.blogspot.ch/

Comment: I would not declare a height, or at least declare it as `auto`. Like this `img{
  height: auto;
  min-width: 100%; }`

Comment: Please don't "delete" a question by changing the question to something like "I have solved the question" or "I no longer need a answer". A question should never be changed to something different. I made a rollback for that reason. A alternative to your edit is to delete the question (maybe you need to flag for moderator atention for that).

Answer (score 2):

if you do :

```
img {
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

You tell your image to be at least 100% of the width of the its container and always 100% of the height of its container.

Try these :

```
/* 1OO% of the container's width and proportional height */
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

/* 1OO% of the container's height and proportional width */
img {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

/* 1OO% of the image's original width maximum and proportional height, resize the image down if needed but prevent the image to be bigger than its original size */
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
};
```

Comment: I did try all of these. 1st and 3rd do set the right ratio, but there is a cap as well, I want the picture to cover the whole space.
The 2nd does do that, but the image is not in its initial ratio anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i managed to get the picture to right aspect ratio.
but is that good?

im not sure what you are trying to do..

CSS CODE:

```
height: 300px !important;
min-width: initial !important;
overflow: hidden;
```

**Edit:**
I think the best way is to create in photoshop all images.. and do it pre defined area to dimensions that you know.

Comment: This does set the right ratio, but my aim i for the image to cover the whole space, with this there is space uncovered.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove this: `min-width: 100% !important;`.
Generally, you should avoid using `!important` rules.

If you want to keep the aspect ratio, image `width` need to be set to `auto` (without being overridden by `min-width`). See how you can change your CSS to make it so.

And btw. you might want to clear up that CSS or write it from scratch, as the same rules are written on 6-7 different lines, which is really bad.

EDIT

To fix it the hard way, add these rules to your image:

```
width: auto; // keeps the aspect ratio
max-width: initial !important;  // overrides the default !important rules set by Blogger (?)
height: 100%; // stretches the image vertically inside the parent element
```

Comment: Yeah, clearing is the next step. First I want this to work.

I did try height: 100% and width: auto, but it's still pushed together.

Comment: It's because you have that rule `min-width: 100% !important;` defined all over the place, and it overrides pretty much whatever you do. If you want to do it the hard way, try adding: `min-width: initial !important;` as well to your element.

Comment: I just searched in the editor and couldn't find any min-width: 100%. Blogger does add a lot of CSS I can't edit. Do you think that's where that's coming from?
The hard way didn't work...

Comment: Give me a min to check our your website.

Comment: thanks for your help but I think I just have to give up on this. It doesn't work. Again the thing happening is the image leaving space underneath it, while it has full width. I think I will just reduce it to 3 tiles in a row and then I can reduce the height so width is bigger than height.

Comment: That space is coming from the `.view` element. Set its height to 240px instead of 200 and it will cover properly. However, there are TONS of bad code parts there. We could spend whole day solving them one by one.

Comment: Yeah I know. Actually I just think I'll ditch the idea completely and start all over again. I think I might go crazy if I tried longer.
THANKS a lot for your help though!